# Want to import these images in to google sheet

Tags: image, google-sheets, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want to import these images from this category from this website https://www.daraz.pk/slicers-dicers/?from=onesearch_category_10000339&item_id=240649787&page=1&spm=a2a0e.searchlistcategory.card.3.47b52857rExtdT

Need a Formula to put in google sheet and boom images came there

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You cannot access those images. The images on that website are generated dynamically with Javascript. You can confirm this by looking at the Page Source and trying to find any image (or any content for that matter).